# Upload file in node.js and POST multipart in spring boot

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How send files uploaded in node.js (multipart) through http, something like this:

```
var options = {
  host: url,
  port: 8080,
  path: '/sendFile',
  method: 'POST'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
}).end();
```

In http request, how it's possible to send file uploaded in multipart form?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. There are diverse strategies.

The simplest is to use the correct by using the .form() feature from request, sonmething like:

```
var form = req.form();
form.append('file', file_content, {
filename: 'myfile.ext',
contentType: 'corresponding content/type'
});
```

And then do the post Request

... or you can stream it and let request extract the data required

```
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('path/to/file'));
```